# Edit WooCommerce Shop page, Title before thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've bitten off more than I can chew and need some help with WooCommerce.

I'm trying to edit the shop front page (i've managed to do the product single pages fine) but can't find the out put for the hooks anywhere.

Basically, all i'm trying to do is make the Title of the product appear before the thumbnail and add a"view" button after the thumbnail.

I'm literally pulling my hair out so if anyone could help i'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: Did you copy the plugin templates into your theme and adapted? If not, it's well explained in the docs. Better read the docs than pulling hair out ;)

Comment: Yup done all that, read all the docs. The docs are brief at best!

Answer (score 0):

You should to see in plugin/woocommerce/woocommerce-hook.php

Form Line 100 - 107

```
/**
 * Before Single Products Summary Div
 *
 * @see woocommerce_show_product_images()
 * @see woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails()
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );

/**
```

Form Line 120 - 132

```
/**
 * Product Summary Box
 *
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_title()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_price()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_excerpt()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_meta()
 * @see woocommerce_template_single_sharing()
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );

/**
```

Change order of add_action
Change value of the second arg

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add below on function.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 90 );
```

Adding above code will duplicate you thumbnail, then add below CSS will do trick.

```
.product-images { display: none; }
```